# WINAPI SQLite C unable to insert data to DB properly

Tags: c++, sqlite, winapi

The program compiles and runs properly but does problem in writing to DB i dont know why
Here is the code:

```
sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt;

char *_sql = "INSERT INTO BOOKS(ID,BOOKNAME,ISSUER,RETURNED) VALUES(@id,@bname,@iss,@ret);";

if(sqlite3_prepare(_db, _sql, 300, &insertStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    MessageBox(*hw,L"Prepared!",L"Info",MB_OK);
else
    MessageBox(*hw,(LPWSTR)CharToWChar(sqlite3_errmsg(_db)),L"INFO",MB_OK);

int paramidx1 = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(insertStmt, "@idx");
int paramidx2 = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(insertStmt, "@bname");
int paramidx3 = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(insertStmt, "@iss");
int paramidx4 = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(insertStmt, "@return");
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, paramidx1, arg1, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, paramidx2, arg2, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, paramidx3, arg3, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(insertStmt, paramidx4, arg4, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

MessageBox(*hw,L"Stepping into insert statement",L"INFO",MB_OK);

if (sqlite3_step(insertStmt) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    wcscpy(ermsg,CharToWChar("Error in inserting statement or in DB."));
    MessageBox(*hw,(LPWSTR)CharToWChar(sqlite3_errmsg(_db)),L"INFO",MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

When i for example enter 12 as id, "XYZ" as bname, "ABC" as iss, 34 as return..
In database it is:

```
1    X    A    3
```

each at respective columns.
need help please.

Answer (score 1):

From the remainder of your code, it looks like you are saving UNICODE strings. I can't see the types of `arg1, 2, 3, 4` but you might like to try replacing

```
sqlite3_bind_text(/* ... */);
```

with

```
sqlite3_bind_text16(/* ... */);
```

You might also need to check that all is compatible with the default encoding in your database. As it says [in the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html):

> The default encoding for the database will be UTF-8 if sqlite3_open() or sqlite3_open_v2() is called and UTF-16 in the native byte order if sqlite3_open16() is used.

There are some [PRAGMA statements](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding) you can use too:

> **PRAGMA encoding;**
>   **PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-8";**
>   **PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-16";**
>   **PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-16le";**
>   **PRAGMA encoding = "UTF-16be";**
>
> In first form, if the main database has already been created, then
>   this pragma returns the text encoding used by the main database, one
>   of "UTF-8", "UTF-16le" (little-endian UTF-16 encoding) or "UTF-16be"
>   (big-endian UTF-16 encoding). If the main database has not already
>   been created, then the value returned is the text encoding that will
>   be used to create the main database, if it is created by this session.
>
> The second through fifth forms of this pragma set the encoding that
>   the main database will be created with if it is created by this
>   session. The string "UTF-16" is interpreted as "UTF-16 encoding using
>   native machine byte-ordering". It is not possible to change the text
>   encoding of a database after it has been created and any attempt to do
>   so will be silently ignored.
>
> Once an encoding has been set for a database, it cannot be changed.

Comment: those variables are of type const char

Comment: @electruxenergy ok, so how are you reading them back from the database?

Comment: @electruxenergy yes, but you said *"in database it is 1 X A ..."* - how do you see that?